# Span id value not scraped with excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the Excel code which scrapes match results from nowgoal.com which stopped working recently, despite no changes in nowgoal page structure

Cell AF2 contains "1" what controls for which rows data should be scraped (basically each row with number 1 added in column A should be processed with scraping).

Each rows contain nowgoal ID (http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/1401651.html - ID is 1401651) and home goals should be scraped to column C and away goals to column D in each respective row)

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Milliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub GetResult()

Const START_ROW As Integer = 3
Const START_COL As Integer = 3

Const ANALYSIS_PAGE As String = "http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/"

Dim LString As String, LArray() As String

'get week number
Dim week As Integer: week = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 32)

'instantiate worksheet to process
Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = ActiveSheet

'instantiate browser
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True

'instantiate variables
Dim url As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim nowGoalID As Long, iRow As Long, lastRow As Long

With wks

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For iRow = START_ROW To lastRow

        'check week
        If .Cells(iRow, 1) <> week Or .Cells(iRow, 2) = "" Then GoTo nextRow
        Application.Goto .Cells(iRow, 1), True
        DoEvents

        nowGoalID = .Cells(iRow, 2)
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing row: " & iRow & " " & nowGoalID

        url = ANALYSIS_PAGE & nowGoalID & ".html"

        ie.navigate url
        While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Sleep 100: Wend
        While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Sleep 100: Wend

        LString = Mid(ie.document.getElementById("mScore").innerText, 8)
        LArray = Split(LString, "-")

        Cells(70, 2).Value = LArray

nextRow:
Next iRow
End With

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
MsgBox "All done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Macro opens IE and find the proper website however scraping is not done

Comment: Could you supply a couple more ids?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to concatenate the id into an ajax xhr

```
Option Explicit    
Public Sub GetScores()
    Dim arr() As String, ws As Worksheet, ids(), id As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ids = Array(1692803, 1401651)

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For id = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)
            .Open "GET", "http://www.nowgoal.com/Ajax.aspx?type=24&id=" & ids(id) & "&p=1553884659000", False
            .send
            If .Status = 200 Then
                arr = Split(.responseText, "-")
                ws.Cells(id + 1, "C") = arr(0): ws.Cells(id + 1, "D") = arr(1)
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?